# How should electronic products' power requirements be labeled?

Tags: markings, compliance

I work for a lab device manufacturing firm that manufactures centrifuges, stirrers, vortex mixers, etc. There are two types of devices: AC and DC-operated. In the case of DC-operated devices, for the barcode sticker placed on the product, which input value should we mention on it?

Should we mention the output value mentioned on the adapter as an input on the sticker, or is there a need to mention the exact value according to the power consumption? I want to clarify that we do mention input and power consumption separately on the sticker.

Comment: If you were the one reading the label trying to find out something you need, what would you want to see?

Comment: I would want to see the value given on the adapter as an input on the product with also the mention of actual power consumption value.

Comment: What do you mean "the exact value"?

Comment: Typically you’d specify the minimum capacity of a power supply that is suitable for the device, so somewhat above the maximum power consumption of the device itself.

Comment: Have you looked at what other folk do on their similar products? Have you checked what is required legally for your industry?

Comment: Yes, I have seen similar products but mostly all of them were AC-operated & my concern is about DC-operated devices.

Answer (score 3):

You should mention the worst case steady state power that the device can be expected to draw under any use case, rounded up to at most two significant figures. "Steady state" here basically means more than a second or so.

When a user looks at the label they want to know what kind of power supply is required to operate it, either because they lost the original supply or because it broke. They need to know the voltage, the polarity, and the maximum current. They don't need to know how much extra power the original supply could deliver.

There is of course some freedom when rounding, if it draws 850 mA it could make sense to write 1 A. But if it draws 500 mA you wouldn't necessarily want to inconvenience the user by writing a value twice what is necessary.

Comment: Unless a precise voltage is required, a range should be displayed, and if it is critical, a tolerance should be specified.

Comment: I've always wanted to see a tolerance, or a safe range, on DC-input devices. My cigarette lighter USB power supply bought for a car says '8 V - 28 V input' on it, which is very helpful, when I have random batteries and laptop power supplies kicking around. But it would confuse some people. My ADSL just says '12 V'. Am I going to blow that up with a 15 V wall-wart? Probably not, but am I feeling lucky?

Comment: Yes, I understand pipe but won't it be appropriate if we provide the exact same value of the output of the power adapter as an input value in the barcode? As by opting for this way customer would have the exact idea that which adapter they need to use incase they need to opt for the new one.

Comment: @Harsh Well, then it becomes a marketing decision, basically "Let's lie to the customer because we don't want to ship a suitable power supply or write the product name on it", sort of like writing "Warranty void if removed" on a sticker that carries no legal weight.

Comment: @pipe It's not like that I am just asking to put the output value of the adapter on the barcode sticker as we do test our products for EMC-EMI & Safety at third-party labs with the adapters we provide with our products. The rating of the adapter is mentioned in the test reports with its photograph. So if we are going to provide another rating to the product & if the customer is going to use a different adapter then would the test reports be valid in that case?

Comment: Also as I have clarified in the question we do provide the actual power consumption of the product on the sticker so the customers would have information about the actual rating on which device operates.

Answer (score 0):

The power into the adapter and the power used by the product would be almost the same (unless the adapter was very inefficient).  That's because the adapter doesn't consume the power; it is passed on to the product.

I could imagine a label like this:  `Input: DC 12 volts, (+) center.  For use with 90W AC Adapter.`

Comment: "90W or above" would be better, people dont know you can use a larger one

Answer (score 0):

It depends but usually most products have to be tested through an NRTL before you put them on the market (such as UL or TUV). If you did send the products through in an NRTL and got certified then is the values that are listed on the NRTL certification.

For DC stickers you need to use the same voltage and Max current that the device can draw.

Answer (score 0):

Something as: 240V/120V AC to 12V DC adapter,Current 850mA ,12 Volts If its AC to DC input.

If its just DC: 12V DC, current 500mA.

Usually, power drawn in watts is not written on the device.

You would want the user to find a suitable adapter in future so you have to specify voltage and current draw in exact figures in milli scale and perhaps the adapter can list maximum voltage and possibly have cut off features incase of over voltage.